# Bucket Sort implementation in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, sorting, bucket-sort

I've been implementing different sorting algorithms in Objective-C (quicksort, mergesort, bubblesort). But I haven't found any clear implementation of Bucket Sort algorithm

I'm trying to find a simple and efficient implementation of Bucket Sort algorithm in objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it my self, here's my implementation if anyone needs it:

```
- (NSArray*)bucketSort:(NSArray<NSNumber*> *)array buckets:(NSInteger)k {

    // Initialize array of buckets
    NSMutableArray<NSMutableArray*> *buckets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:k];
    for (int i=0; i < buckets.count; i++)
        buckets[i] = [NSMutableArray new];

    // Add elements to buckets
    for (int i=0; i < buckets.count; i++) {
        NSInteger index = k * array[i].floatValue; // Asuming "array" has values between 0 and 1
        if (index < buckets.count) [buckets[index] addObject:array[i]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    // Sort individual buckets
    // Concatenate all sorted buckets in order
    for (int i=0; i < buckets.count; i++) {
        buckets[i] = [self quickSort:buckets[i]]; // Sorting algorithm like quicksort/mergesort/insertionsort
        [sortedArray addObjectsFromArray:buckets[i]];
    }

    return sortedArray;
}
```

Comment: You have an `if` with no `else` when adding elements to buckets, so either the `if` is redundant *or* some elements could not be added to any bucket. You could also make it more "efficient" by combining the last two loops, but you'll have to decide whether that meets your "simple" goal. (Sorting floats with Obj-C arrays is never going to be particularly efficient of course, but that is orthogonal to the efficient implementation of the algorithm *per se*.) HTH

Comment: @CRD You are right, the `if` with no `else` is intended, it's just a safe-check not to go out of bounds in the array and crash the program. An exception or error report should go on the `else` probably. Thanks for the note on the last two loops, I will correct the solution. Would you recommend a different collection for the implementation of this algorithm in Obj-C ?

Comment: If you really are sorting a large number of basic values (integers, floating point) then using standard C value arrays (which can be dynamically allocated) is going to be faster than Objective-C object arrays (where the array itself is an object and contains your values wrapped as objects). This is regardless of sorting algorithm. For small numbers of values (so the overhead is negligible), and of course for objects, you would use normally use object based collections.